# How to calculate compound angles

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, angle

How can I calculate the compound angle when I know two of the angles but don't know what the angle would be where the two intersect?

[image]

If "A" and "C" are sitting on a 9.16 degree angle and the are coming together at a 90 degree angle in the corner, how can the compound angle of "A" and "C" be determined? In the past, I would try 3d modeling such a space and testing the angles and trying to figure it out by stepping backwards, but I feel that there must be a simpler and more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

One method would be to construct vectors $n_A$ and $n_C$ 
perpendicular to the two
surfaces $A$ and $C,$ then use the formula
$$
n_A \cdot n_C = \|n_A\| \|n_C\| \cos \theta_{AC}.
$$
Solve this for $\theta_{AC},$ the angle between the surfaces.

This formula works reasonably well in the given example since the angle between the surfaces is not too far from $90$ degrees.
Angles near $90$ degrees give good results because
$\frac{d}{d\theta} \cos\theta$ is maximized when $\theta$ is
$90$ degrees.
If you try this method for surfaces that are nearly parallel,
you run into the fact that when $\cos\theta \approx 1,$
a small error in the value of $\cos\theta$ translates into a
much larger error in the value of $\theta.$

Comment: Since you included some practical considerations, I'll add one more. The opposite vector $-\mathbf n_A$ is also a possible normal of surface $A$. If you use normals $-\mathbf n_A$ with $\mathbf n_C$ you then obtain angle $\pi-\theta_{AC}$. So in general you need to be careful in how you choose your normals, if you include this computation in an automated process/algorithm. If this is a one-time thing, you should still confirm which angle $\theta_{AC}$ or $\pi-\theta_{AC}$ is the right one.

Comment: Another way to view the $\theta_{AC}$ vs. $\pi - \theta_{AC}$ concern is that the normal-vector method considers an entire _plane,_ not just a polygon on one side of a line of intersection. The intersection of two planes produces two angles, supplementary to each other. So you really need to be careful to pick the right one. It's even possible to run afoul of _both_ of these concerns: surfaces nearly parallel, but because you used $-n_A$ instead of $n_A$ you end up with $\cos\theta \approx -1,$ which again is not good for accurately computing $\theta.$

Answer (score 0):

If we choose axis $x$ along the separation line between $A$ and $B$, axis $y$ along the separation line between $C$ and $D$, axis $z$ perpendicular to plane $BD$, then it is not difficult to find two unit vectors normal to $A$ and $C$, both directed "inwards":
$$
n_A=(0,\sin\theta,-\cos\theta),
\quad
n_C=(\sin\theta,0,-\cos\theta),
$$
where $\theta$ is the dihedral angle between planes $A/B$ (and $C/D$).

The angle $\alpha$ between the vectors satisfies then 
$\cos\alpha=n_A\cdot n_C=\cos^2\theta$. The dihedral angle $\phi$ between planes $A/C$ is the supplementary of $\alpha$ and we have then the very simple relation:
$$
\cos\phi=-\cos^2\theta.
$$
For the given example:
$$
\cos\phi=-\cos^2 99.16°=-0.0253421,
\quad \phi=91.45°.
$$