# Compound angles formula derivation(crown molding)

Tags: geometry, 3d, angle, dihedral-groups

So I've been trying to get my head around this for a week now. It's a practical problem, but the geometry seems more involved then I initially thought. 
When you want to attach a crown molding to a wall with a certain spring angle and wall angle, you can cut the molding laying flat with a miter saw, setting both miter and bevel angle to a certain degree, as illustrated here:
https://www.blocklayer.com/crown-molding.aspx

The formula behind this calculator is as follows:
$$Miter = \arctan(\cos(B) * \tan(A/2)) \\
Bevel = \arcsin(\sin(B) * \sin(A/2)) $$
With $A$ the wall angle and $B$ the spring angle.

Now my real question is, how to arrive at these formulas?
I've made a number of drawings, but frankly they are all awful :)
I've tried composing the normal vectors as in this answer:
[How to calculate compound angles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2638529/how-to-calculate-compound-angles)

But didn't get too far. 
Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can find a comprehensive explanation at the following link. If there is anything else you need help on, just leave a comment under this answer.

http://jansson.us/nsideboxderive.html

Comment: Thanks!! I saw a ton of calculator sites, but none with a detailed (and graphical!) explanation. 
I can see clearly now :)

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Try to draw a 3d trig right angled triangles yourself.

Given are the angles $( A,B).$

Since you cutting away one half you need to consider only its half angle $( A/2)$ at corner.

See where unit edge length $1$ comes in. Draw its components in a right triangle involving angle $B$:

$$( \sin B, \cos B )$$

Recognize in these right triangles required angles $(Mit,Bev)$

$$ \dfrac{\sin Bev}{\sin A/2} = \sin B  $$

$$ \dfrac{\tan Mit}{\tan A/2} = \cos B . $$